# copy a file into all sub directories php

Tags: php

I have a text file that I want to copy into all sub directories which have the following structure.

```
S000314/0000356/data folder  
/0000357/data folder  
/0000358/data folder
```

So, I am reading all the sub directories and trying to copy the text file into all of them..But, rename function can copy only once.its copying the text file into 0000356->data folder

```
if ($handle = opendir('S000314')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..")
        {
            rename("sdata.txt" , "/S000314/$entry/data/sdata.txt");
        }       
    }
    closedir($handle); 
}
```

I have no clue on how to copy the same file into all of the sub directories.Please take a look at the code below.

Comment: There is a PHP function called [`copy()`](http://php.net/copy) - did you try that already? Also you should check if `$entry` really [`is_dir()`](http://php.net/is_dir)

Comment: Yes, I did ..But, That didn't work.

Comment: My directory contains all subdirectories,,Nothing else..That's why i didn't include is_dir()

Comment: assuming your not running the PHP in the '/' directory, then trying to rename to the absolute /S000314 is the wrong place.  try using './S000314'  Also, rename will MOVE the file not copy, so use copy()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using [`copy()`](http://www.php.net/copy) instead of `rename()` because that is the actual operation you want (the code will be easier to read).

A problem could be the directory separator - I tested it on Windows where both `/` and `\` seems to be working, but that shouldn't be your concern, as PHP has [`DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php).

Now this code worked on my machine:

```php
$topdir = 'S000314';
if ($handle = opendir($topdir)) {
    print "in\n";
    while (FALSE !== ($subdir = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($subdir != '.' && $subdir != '..') {
            $dest = $topdir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 
                $subdir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR 
                'data' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
            copy('data.txt', $dest.'data.txt');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Implemented your suggestion , it didn't work .here is the code $topdir = '../simulations/S000611/';
if ($handle = opendir($topdir)) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
  $dest = $topdir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 
                $entry . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 
                'data' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
            echo "$dest\n";
   //echo $dir.PHP_EOL;
   $file ="../data/sdata.txt" ;
   copy($file , $dest."sdata.txt");
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}

Comment: You need to debug this further. Are you sure the loop is properly run through? Are those subdirectories actually writeable?

Comment: I have used  echo "$dest\n"; in the script..It is printing out all the paths perfectly,,,but, its not copying.

Comment: Check the deepest subdir with [`is_writable()`](http://php.net/is_writable) and be sure to use (as you always should in development!) [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/error_reporting)

Answer (score 0):

```
@copy($yourSource_file, $yourFile_element . '/youPage.html');
```